# apt install virtualenv vs apt install python3-virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, apt

This question has many related questions, but none answers what I want to know:

I usually work like this:

1. install python 3.5+
2. sudo apt install virtualenv
3. virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.* bla
4. . bla/bin/activate
5. pip install & run python

This seems to work perfectly, and I've done so also with python2.7. Is there a difference between using `apt install virtualenv` and `apt install python3-virtualenv`?

Answer (score 1):

Package virtualenv is described here: https://packages.debian.org/buster/virtualenv or https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtualenv. When you look at the files it contains you see that it consists only of a bit of documentation.

But virtualenv has dependencies packages python3 and python3-virtualenv. So if you install virtualenv those packages will also be installed.

Python 2 is not supported by upstream anymore, not even security fixes. So you simply should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

`apt install virtualenv` shall install `python3-virtualenv` as well I am pretty sure about that but I think that depends on what appears when you enter python on your terminal it is supposed to be version dependent.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I can say that package `virtulenv` is an overlay over `python-virtualenv`(Python 2 Virtual Env creator) and `python3-virtualenv`(Python 3 virtual Env creator). It is essential for command `virtualenv` to work (the one you type in terminal). Now, this command can internally use either of 2 versions provided by python.

Therefore, if you do `sudo apt install virtualenv` it automatically installs `python3-virtualenv` along with it. However, you can install virtualenv with `python2-virtualenv` as well.

So, difference is that `virtualenv` package is the one which provides command line options(invokable via terminal) while python3-virtualenv(for python 3) does actual job of creating environment and is replaceable by python-virtualenv(for python 2).

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install `virtualenv`, I can confirm that it installs the `python3-virtualenv`

[virtualenv install on linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDfSQ.png)

So, concur with the previous answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34140937)